# Output and Import list of lists to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, import, output

I want to be able to append to a `.txt` file each time I run a function.

The output I am trying to write to the function is something like this:

```
somelist = ['a','b','b','c']
somefloat = -0.64524
sometuple = (235,633,4245,524)
output = tuple(somelist,somefloat,sometuple) (the output does not need to be in tuple format.)
```

Right now, I am outputting like this:

```
outfile = open('log.txt','a')
out = str(output)+'\n
outfile.write(out)
```

This kind of works, but I have to import it like this:

```
with open('log.txt', "r") as myfile:
    mydata = myfile.readlines()
    for line in mydata:  
        line = eval(line)
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to import it back directly into a Pandas DataFrame something like this:

```
dflog = pd.read_csv('log.txt')
```

and have it generate a three column dataset with the first column containing a list (string format is fine), the second column containing a float, and the third column containing a tuple (same deal as the list).

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to append the output in a format that can be more easily imported into pandas
2. Is there a simpler way of doing this, this seems like a pretty common task, I wouldn't be surprised if somebody has made this into a line or two of code.

Comment: What's the expected output? Can you put an example of the pandas dataframe you would expect to have from that `pd.read_csv` command?

Comment: Output would be a three column dataset with the first column containing ['a','b','b','c'], the second column containing -0.64524, and the third containing (235,633,4245,524).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to separate your columns with a custom separator such as `'|'`

Say:

```
somelist = ['a','b','b','c']
somefloat = -0.64524
sometuple = (235,633,4245,524)
output = str(somelist) + "|" + str(somefloat) + "|" + str(sometuple)
```

(if you wanna have many more columns, then use `string.join()` or something like that)

Then, just as before:

```
outfile = open('log.txt','a')
out = output + '\n'
outfile.write(out)
```

As just read the whole file with

```
pd.read_csv("log.txt", sep='|')
```

Do note that using lists or tuples for an entry in `pandas`is discouraged (I couldn't find a official reference for that though). For speedups with operations, you might consider dividing your tuples or lists into separate columns so that you're left with floats, integers or simple strings. Pandas can easily handle automatic naming if you so need.

Comment: This works.  I wouldn't want to give each entry inside of the list and tuple it's own column because they aren't going to be a fixed number of items going forward and I want to be able to grab the contents of the column without having to reference a dynamic number of columns when I use the output going forward.  Thanks for the help!